# Set in which each element is also a subset of the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction

I'm trying to figure out a set $S$, such that each element $x \in S $ can also be $x \subseteq S$.

My idea is that, as we know that the empty set is subset of every set, then $\emptyset \subseteq S$. Subsequently if $S=\{\emptyset\}$, then I can say that $x \in S $ and $x \subseteq S$, where $x = \emptyset$.

Then, if I extend $S$ to be $S=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},...\}$, then $\{\emptyset\}$ is also an element and a subset of $S$, and so on.

Would this be a correct idea? And if it is correct, can it be proven by induction to show it applies to any size of set $S$?

Comment: $\varnothing$ is the simplest such set (there are no elements, so vacuously each element is a subset). $\{\varnothing\}$ is the next one (there is only the empty set as an element, and the empty set is always a subset of anything). In general, they're called _transitive sets_ because the "each element is a subset" condition may be rewritten into "If $x\in y$ and $y\in S$, then $x\in S$", which is to say, the "relation" $\in$ satisfies the property commonly called transitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct and can be used to define natural numbers.

Another (more common) construction is defining: $0:=\varnothing$, $1:=\{0\}$, $2:=\{0,1\}$, $3:=\{0,1,2\}$ et cetera.

Then $0,1,2,3,\dots$ are all **transitive** (see comment of @Arthur) sets, and also $\omega=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ can be shown to be transitive.